# Cannot executing a SQL query through ODP.NET - invalid character error

Tags: oracle, odp.net, ora-00911

I'm trying to execute a SQL query through ODP.NET to create a table, but I always get an ORA-00911 'invalid character' error. The Errors object in the exception always has the text "ORA-00911: invalid character\n", even if there are no linebreaks in the SQL query itself.

The code I'm executing the SQL is this:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(<connection string>) {
using (OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    conn.Open();
    command.CommandText = queryString;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();         // exception always gets thrown here
}
```

queryString contains a single CREATE TABLE statement, which works fine when executed through SQL Developer

EDIT: the SQL I am executing is this:

```
CREATE TABLE "TESTSYNC"."NEWTABLE" (
  "COL1" NUMBER(*,0) NULL,
  "COL2" NUMBER(*,0) NULL
);
```

with linebreaks removed

Comment: Can you post the comment text please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Other people](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=618125&#618125) have come across this issue - ODP.NET does not support multiple SQL statements in a text command. The solution is to wrap it in a PL/SQL block with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE around each statement. This lack of support for ; seems incredibly boneheaded to me, and has not improved my opinion of the oracle development team.

Furthermore, this seems to be an issue with oracle itself, as I have the same problems with the MS and ODBC oracle clients.

Comment: it seems that year 2013 still hasn't brought us support for this?!

Comment: Can you elaborate with a code example? Some of us don't really know much pl.

Comment: For others arriving here, as @thecoop mentions in another comment, if you only have one statement, remove the ; at the end.  That was my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for some reason you have to have code on one line. 
I had strSQL = "stuff" +
  " more stuff"
I had to put it on one line.
strSQL = "stuff more stuff"

It some how reads the cr/lf.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your sql in a **Begin** block.

```
Dim sqlInsert As String = ""
For i = 1 To 10
    sqlInsert += "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (COUNT) VALUES (" & i & "); "
Next

Call ExecuteSql("BEGIN " & sqlInsert & " END;")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are OK (it just forces Oracle to treat your object names as case sensitive i.e. upper case the way you've written it) but I'm not at all sure you're allowed to define NUMBER that way with a *.

Comment: That's the syntax obtained from dbms_metadata.get_ddl where the column is created with datatype INT

Comment: I've had a play around, and what it's actually complaining about is the ; at the end - removing that makes the sql statement run without problems. That, however, seems incredibly bizarre to me.

Comment: you could maybe setup TKPROF to run on your database server to see what SQL is being generated by your OracleCommand object (i.e. to see if the ";" is generated automatically)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it is the "*" in the sql have you tried the call without an * in the create?  I bet it is yet another "feature" of the ODP.Net driver

Comment: It's not the *, its the ; at the end that it's complaining about

Comment: You shouldn't need a ; to execute a statement like that.  At least I have never needed one against oracle.